# How to specify encoding to fileinput

Tags: python

In Python how do I specify the encoding to [fileinput.input](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html)?

I wrote

```
f = fileinput.input(openhook=fileinput.hook_encoded("windows-1252"))
```

but it doesn't work reliably. I get different results for `script.py text.txt` and `script.py < text.txt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the fileinput module, it only uses the the encoding information when reading from files, not when reading from standard input :(

Comment: The bug seems to have been fixed in Python 3.